# Does the placement of a condition matter?

Tags: sql, postgresql

The 2 following queries are giving me different results:

```
SELECT A.source_code, B.quantity
FROM Table_A AS A
LEFT JOIN Table_B AS B ON B.merchant_id = A.merchant_id
   AND B.agent_id = A.agent_id
   AND B.default IS NULL
WHERE A.month='2011-10-01'
   AND B.type='600'
```

And

```
SELECT A.source_code, B.quantity
FROM Table_A AS A
LEFT JOIN Table_B AS B ON B.merchant_id = A.merchant_id
   AND B.agent_id = A.agent_id
WHERE A.month='2011-10-01'
   AND B.type='600'
   AND B.default IS NULL
```

I had assumed that the condition does the same operation on both queries, only at different times. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are and should be different.

Consider the case where you have an a with a b that matches on merchant and agend id's, and b.default is not null.

In the first case, you will find the a, and then find no b's that meet the criteria, because there is no b that matches on the id's AND has default is null. But because it's a left join, you still get a record with the "a" data in the output.

In the second case, you will find the a and find a matching b. But because b fails the WHERE clause, the record is excluded from the output.

If you are doing a full join, putting a condition in an ON versus a WHERE will not change the output. But on a left or right join, it DOES change the output in the way I tried to describe above.

Answer (score 1):

The first will show you only matching records from B that also have a value of `NULL` for `default`.

The second variant will show you all the records from `B`, since the filter is being applied after the `OUTER JOIN` is executed.  Since unmatched records show up with `NULL` values, this matches all records.

However, you should also be aware that when you filter on the `JOIN`ed table in the `WHERE` clause you are forcing an `INNER JOIN`, so you actually have two issues at work here.

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly, but in this case yes.

The WHERE clause filters the result set, whereas the ON clause stop rows from joining in the first place. The result set could large, making a lot of work in handling the large result set. If you were to join to other tables, it would make a large difference, because stopping rows joining earlier can cut off massive amounts of rows later on.

Most modern parsers will optimize the query anyway, so the performance effect should be the same either way.

Finally, because the WHERE clause filters, the left join will *keep* at least one row with the condition in the ON clause, but throw it out with the condition in the WHERE clause.

Comment: That's the thing. I do have other joins in my actual query, and there is a large noticeable difference. But the first case is yielding more cases than the second. Intuitively, like you said, shouldn't it be the other way around?